# jQuery disable and enable scrolling in conjunction with slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm rather new to jQuery and I was thinking how do I first disable scrolling on the first click of a slideToggle event to slide the div down, and then enable scrolling on the second click when toggling the div back up?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $('html, body').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

With my current code I can slide the div down and disable scrolling, and when sliding the div back up it still keeps scrolling disabled.

HTML:

```
<div id="flip" class="page-header" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('sample.jpg');">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
         <div class="brand">
            <h2 class="audiowide-font">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $('html, body').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    })
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
  #panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #353839;
}

#panel {
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
  display: none;
  ove
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip" class="page-header" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('sample.jpg');">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <div class="brand">
          <h2 class="audiowide-font">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
text to get scrollbar<br>
```

Comment: can you add you html code also?

Comment: If you are having any issues in `Js` or `CSS` related things it's always better to create a code snippet with the current state of your problem. that helps SO users to understand your problem better and can help you faster. it ok to share limited code but the actual problem which you facing may not be in this. hope you understood what i meand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here I just added a checking if the `panel` is **visible**. if it is visible it will prevent scrolling else will follow the normal flow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  
  $('html, body').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e) {
    if($("#panel").is(':visible')){ //checks wether #panel is visible or hidden
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #353839;
}

#panel {
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
  display: none;
  ove
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip" class="page-header" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('sample.jpg');">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <div class="brand">
          <h2 class="audiowide-font">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
  text to get scrollbar<br>
</div>
```